# How to split and merge models together in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to build a stacked autoencoder model composed of 2 autoencoders. I have the 2 AEs but I'm unable to join them.

This is what I have so far

```
### AUTOENCODER 1 ###
X_input = Input(input_shape)
x = Conv2D(64, (4,1), activation='relu', padding='same')(X_input)
x = Conv2D(32, (3,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(name='encoded')(x)
encoded_shape = x.shape.as_list()

x = Conv2D(32, (3,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D(name='up1')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (4,1), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(1, (3,3), name='decoded', padding='same')(x)
ae1 = Model(X_input, x)

enc_layer_ae1 = ae1.get_layer('encoded').output
```

-

```
### AUTOENCODER 2 ###
X_input1 = Input(encoded_shape[1:])
x1 = Conv2D(24, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(X_input1)
x1 = Conv2D(16, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x1 = MaxPooling2D((2,3), name='encoded')(x1)

x1 = UpSampling2D((2,3), name='up')(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(16, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(24, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x1)
x1 = Conv2D(32, (1,1), padding='same')(x1)

ae2 = Model(X_input1, x1)

enc_layer_ae2 = ae2.get_layer('encoded').output
```

At this point what I would like to do is to create another model by stacking

- `ae1` layers from 0 up to `encoded`
- the same layers for `ae2`
- some more `Dense` layers

So in the end my model should look like something like `ae1_input > ae1_conv2d > ae1_conv2d > ae1_encoded > ae2_input > ae2_conv > ae2_conv > ae2_encoded > dense > softmax`

I've tried doing something like

```
ae2_split = Model(X_input1, enc_layer_ae2)

full_output = ae2_split(enc_layer_ae1)
full_output = Dense(150, activation='relu')(full_output)
full_output = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(full_output)

full_model = Model(enc_layer_ae1.input, full_output)
```

But I don't think it's correct. Could you suggest me a proper way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should change the input of `enc_layer_ae2` layer. Since layers are callable in keras you can easliy call one layer on an other layer.

```
enc_layer_ae1 = ae1.get_layer('encoded')
enc_layer_ae2 = ae2.get_layer('encoded')

enc_layer_ae2 = enc_layer_ae2(enc_layer_ae1.output)
full_output = Dense(150, activation='relu')(enc_layer_ae2)
full_output = Dense(7, activation='softmax')(full_output)
model = Model(enc_layer_ae1.input, full_output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works, I just needed to add `full_output = Flatten()(enc_layer_ae2)` before the `Dense` layer.  When doing `model.summary` I get something like `encoded | (MaxPooling2D) | multiple` regarding the second ae. Why is the output shape `multiple`? Is there any way to see the full structure of the second ae piece to check that all the dimensions are right?